# How to handle missing data when calculating network homophily/assortativity?

Tags: r, graph-theory, networks, social-network, igraph

I am trying to calculate network homophily/assortativity for a graph. However, some of my nodes have missing values. It turns out igraph's assortativity functions have no "na.rm" function included. As such, any calculation of homophily/assortativity in such a network with even one missing value returns NA, which is a bummer. Is there any proper solution or workaround that allows you to calculate homophily/assortativity even for a network with some missing data? Thanks for any help! Reproducible example below:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(10)
net<-erdos.renyi.game(50,.5)
V(net)$val <- runif(50,0,1)
V(net)$val[sample(1:50,10)] <- NA
assortativity(net, V(net)$val)
```

EDIT: Someone pointed out the correct solution to delete vertices and I have created the below custom function:

```
assortativityNA <- function(graph, types1, types2 = NULL, 
 directed = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE){
  if(na.rm==TRUE){
    graph <- delete_vertices(graph, which(is.na(types1)))
    types1 <- types1[!is.na(types1)]
  }else{
    graph <- graph
  }
  output <- assortativity(graph, types1, types2, directed)
  return(output)
}
```

Comment: I would be careful reporting assortativity when dropping the nodes. Since assortativity is a relation between nodes, dropping nodes with missing data can lead to biased estimates of the assortativity of the network. You might be better off trying some imputation or calculating the bounds